# How to interpret the node code and rejection id on a Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

When running a unit test on a typescript service I am seeing this warning:

`(node:79377) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 6): [object Object]`

What does `node:` tell me? Also, what does `rejection id:` tell me?

--NOTE--

My question is not how to find the unhandled promise, but what the "numbers" in the warning communicate.

Comment: There is an exception you didn't catch

Comment: I recognize that. I want to see if I can get a better understanding of what those numbers are communicating.

Comment: @ponury-kostek this is not a duplicate. He want to know what `79377` and `6` means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(node:79377)` is `node` PID (process ID)
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/process/warning.js#L4

`rejection id` is id of rejected `Promise`
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/process/promises.js#L40 grab `Promise ID`
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/process/promises.js#L63 generate warning/error